# Remove first word in string depending on value of row above in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe below

```
+---------------------+
|         Col         |
+---------------------+
| CATEGORY A          |
| asdwed hello        |
| 8771asd how are you |
| CATEGORY B          |
| hello how are you   |
+---------------------+
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to remove the first word for certain rows only. I.e., for rows below `CATEGORY A`, I should remove the first word, but for rows below `CATEGORY B`, I should not.

One can assume the rows below a category will never have the same string value as a category itself.

Thus the output dataframe would look like

```
+---------------------+
|         Col         |
+---------------------+
| CATEGORY A          |
| hello               |
| how are you         |
| CATEGORY B          |
| hello how are you   |
+---------------------+
```

Dataframe below

```
d = {'col': ['CATEGORY A', 'asdwed hello', '8771asd how are you', 'CATEGORY B', 'hello how are you']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

What is the most Pythonic way of achieving this?

Comment: Your example dataframe has `STRING A` and your printed dataframe has `CATEGORY A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of smart masking and string manipulation to create our boolean array and finally use `loc` to set our values.

```
m1 = df['col'].eq('CATEGORY A')
m2 = df['col'].str.startswith('CATEGORY')
mask = m1.cumsum().eq(m2.cumsum()) & ~m1

df.loc[mask, 'col'] = df.loc[mask, 'col'].str.split(n=1).str[1]


                 col
0         CATEGORY A
1              hello
2        how are you
3         CATEGORY B
4  hello how are you
```

Comment: Yeah index offset should be a variable, it may not always be one or two rows for a certain category

Answer (score 2):

This is rather unwinding and long; @Erfan's answer is shorter and much easier to understand

```
box = (df
      .assign(category=lambda x: np.where(x.Col.str.contains("CATEGORY"), x.Col, np.nan))
      .ffill()
      .query("Col != category")
      .assign(Col=lambda x: np.where(x.category == "CATEGORY A",
                                     x.Col.str.split(n=1).str[-1], x.Col))
      .drop("category", 1))


#update the values of df : 
df.update(box)

df

    Col
0   CATEGORY A
1         hello
2   how are you
3   CATEGORY B
4   hello how are you
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
start = df.col.eq("CATEGORY A").idxmax() + 1  
end = df.col.eq("CATEGORY B").idxmax() - 1

df.loc[start:end, 'col'] = df.loc[start:end, 'col'].str.replace("^(.*?)\s", "")
```

---

```
                 col
0         CATEGORY A
1              hello
2        how are you
3         CATEGORY B
4  hello how are you
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupby` contains string and filter `CATEGORY A` and the alternate. Replace the first word in the substring in the group containing `STRING A` and combine the two dataframes

```
df2=df.groupby(df.col.str.contains('CATEGORY').cumsum()).filter(lambda x:x['col'].str.contains('CATEGORY A').any())
df2.iloc[1:,:].replace(regex=r'(^[^ ]+)',value="", inplace=True)
    
df2.append(df.groupby(df.col.str.contains('CATEGORY').cumsum()).filter(lambda x:~x['col'].str.contains('CATEGORY A').any()))



               col
0           CATEGORY A
1              hello
2        how are you
3           CATEGORY B
4  hello how are you
```